# Live data migration between on-prem MongoDB servers

Tags: mongodb

This is a very theoretical question. Let's say, I am migrating MongoDB 4.4 from the on-prem server into MongoDB 6.0.4 on-prem on another server. The purpose is minimal downtime. The size ~ 1TB. Any suggestion to move it kind of "Live", 5-10 minutes downtime?

Comment: Your question is not theoretical. For a stand-alone server it could be difficult. But you can create a Replica Set (see [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)), then you have almost no downtime, just a restart is needed. After migration you can drop the `local` database to revert the Replica Set to a stand-alone MongoDB.

Comment: My DB's have different versions: 4.4 and 6.0.4. Replication might not work. Any other Ideas? 4.4 is current production, I am afraid to touch it.

Comment: Copy the MongoDB 4.4 binaries to the new server, then you can create the replica set and then you can [upgrade](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-replica-set/). Note, you have to run two upgrades, first 4.4 -> 5.0 and then you can do 5.0 -> 6.0

Comment: Just a general note, the upgrade should not take too much time. You can replace the binaries and then just a restart. While `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` is running, you can still use the application.

Comment: The upgrade is an option but has to be followed by the replica's creation which will add some additional time. The app uses replicas. It will nice to have some tool/mechanism that might sync 2 clusters: the old and new one. Kind of AWS DMS or mongo Atlas live migration, if someone is familiar with such one: will be very nice.